# Laravel db:seed success but no data in my database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I tried to make simple seed in laravel, but when I did "php artisan db:seed", it didn't fill my field.

I made my Categories seeder file 
this is my Categories seeder file :

```
class CategoryTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $categori1 = new Category;
        $categori1->name = "Books";
        $categori1->save();
        $categori2 = new Category;
        $categori2->name = "Backpacks";
        $categori2->save();

    }
}
```

This is my Category model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    //
}
```

And this is part of my Categories table migration file :

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: did you already call the seeder class on database seeder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add your Seeder class to `DatabaseSeeder.php`. Like so:

```
public function run()
{
    $this->call(CategoryTableSeeder::class);
}
```

Or you can specify the exact class that you want to seed with `php artisan db:seed --class=CategoryTableSeeder`.

Answer (score 4):

Run

```
php artisan db:seed --class=CategoryTableSeeder
```

else if you want to run all seeder add this class in file `DatabaseSeeder.php`

```
$this->call(CategoryTableSeeder::class);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happened is because you forgot to add $`fillable` to your model, and define which fields are fillabe. Inside your `Category` add this:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Run your seeder again, you should have desired data.